# AWS auto scaling grroup remove instance from standby without putting in InService

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I kept a faulty ec2 instance to standby in ASG, now want to remove it, without bringing it into InService state.

Is there a way where I can remove the instance directly without bringing instance to InService.

---

### | Standby --> Termination |

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, The instance state transition must go through InService stage and you return the instance to service by exiting the standby state.

[image]

Comment: Even I thought the same, was looking if there was any way to do that.
Thanks for the image, it's real nice :)

Comment: Good to know that :)